# Can wine be made from tomatoes?

Tags: tomatoes, fermentation, wine

Can wine be made from tomatoes? Do they have enough sugar to feed the yeast? Are they too acidic?

Comment: What about kiwi? Your questions could be have merged into one about fermentation of fruit juice and acidity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomatoes can be fermented, and many folks enjoy the result, using them in savory culinary applications  To make a wine, you would probably want to add some ingredients to balance the acidity that most tomatoes bring to the final product.  [Here is an example of one such recipe](https://northeastwinemaking.com/pages/tomato-wine), but I am sure there are others.